# Erro: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Sempre que executo a minha app em alguns dispositivos (Nos que recebi este erro, API era 21. Nos outros com API superior funciona sem erros), aparece esta mensagem de erro que eu não consigo decifrar. Acontece para todos os Fragments da mesma forma, mas a app fecha logo.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: edurbrito.SuperLigaUsers, PID: 2738
              android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                  at edurbrito.SuperLigaUsers.Fragments.Main_Activity_Fragments.ThreeFragment.onCreateView(ThreeFragment.java:71)
                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2261)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1750)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1819)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2590)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2377)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2332)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2209)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:649)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:145)
                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1238)
                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1086)
                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1616)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:714)
                  at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:91)
                  at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1361)
                  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:784)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                at andro ...(O erro acaba assim sem mais explicação ou causa)
```

Este é o layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/sticky_switch"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ColunaClassificacao"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_bg_without_margin"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingStart="7.5dp"
            tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/LugarCC"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="# - "
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/NomeEquipaCC"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Equipa"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:weightSum="5">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/JogosCC"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="JJ"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/PontosCC"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Pts"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/GolosMarcadosCC"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="GM"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/GolosSofridosCC"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="GS"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/DiferençaGolosCC"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="DG"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_three"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_bg2"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ColunaClassificacao">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/switchCampeonato1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_bg_without_margin"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Campeonato"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/switchball3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src = "@drawable/soccer_ball"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

E esta a classe:

```
    import android.Manifest;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
    import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.view.animation.Animation;
    import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.google.gson.Gson;
    import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.lang.reflect.Type;
    import java.nio.charset.Charset;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Set;
    import java.util.TreeMap;

 import edurbrito.SuperLigaUsers.Adapters.RVAdapterClassificacao;
 import edurbrito.SuperLigaUsers.Colunas.ClassificacaoTabela;
 import edurbrito.SuperLigaUsers.Objetos.Campeonato1;
 import edurbrito.SuperLigaUsers.Objetos.Campeonato2;
 import edurbrito.SuperLigaUsers.Objetos.Objeto_Equipa;
 import edurbrito.SuperLigaUsers.R;


public class ThreeFragment extends Fragment {
private final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST = 11;
protected RecyclerView rv;
protected RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
Runnable runnable = null;
private List<ClassificacaoTabela> Classificacao;

public ThreeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView;
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three, container, false);

   final TextView switchCampeonato = rootView.findViewById(R.id.switchCampeonato1);
   final ImageView switchball = rootView.findViewById(R.id.switchball3);

    final Campeonato1 campeonato1 = new Campeonato1();
    final Campeonato2 campeonato2 = new Campeonato2();
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);

    } else {

       switchCampeonato.setText(campeonato1.getNome());
        switchball.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (switchCampeonato.getText().toString().equals(campeonato1.getNome())) {

                    Animation animation;
                    animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),
                            R.anim.rotate);

                    switchball.startAnimation(animation);
                    switchCampeonato.setText(campeonato2.getNome());
                    runnable.run();
                } else {

                    Animation animation;
                    animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),
                            R.anim.rotate);

                    switchball.startAnimation(animation);
                    switchCampeonato.setText(campeonato1.getNome());
                    runnable.run();
                }
            }
        });


        Type MapaTipoEquipas = new TypeToken<Map<String, Objeto_Equipa>>() {
        }.getType();
        String mapaDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/SuperLiga";
        File MapaFile = new File(mapaDirectory, "MapaEquipas1.txt");


        Gson gson = new Gson();


        String string = "";


        try {
            BufferedReader fis2 = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            new FileInputStream(MapaFile),
                            Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            int content;
            while ((content = fis2.read()) != -1) {
                // convert to char and display it
                string += (char) content;
            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Map<String, Objeto_Equipa> mapaEquipas;
        mapaEquipas = gson.fromJson(string, MapaTipoEquipas);

        Set<String> keys = mapaEquipas.keySet();
        String[] listaNomesEqs = keys.toArray(new String[keys.size()]);
        TreeMap<String, Objeto_Equipa> treeMap = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
        for (int i = 0; i < listaNomesEqs.length; i++) {
            treeMap.put(mapaEquipas.get(listaNomesEqs[i]).getFinalString(), mapaEquipas.get(listaNomesEqs[i]));
        }


        List<Objeto_Equipa> targetList = new ArrayList<>(treeMap.values());
        Classificacao = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < targetList.size(); i++) {
            Objeto_Equipa equipa = targetList.get(i);
            Classificacao.add(i, new ClassificacaoTabela("" + (i + 1), equipa.getNome(), equipa.getJogos(), equipa.getPontos(), equipa.getGolosM(), equipa.getGolosS(), equipa.getGolosM() - equipa.getGolosS()));
        }
        rv = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_three);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rv.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


        RVAdapterClassificacao adapter = new RVAdapterClassificacao(Classificacao, getActivity());

        rv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Type MapaTipoEquipas = new TypeToken<Map<String, Objeto_Equipa>>() {
            }.getType();
            String mapaDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/SuperLiga";
            File MapaFile;


           if (switchCampeonato.getText().toString().equals(campeonato1.getNome())) {
               MapaFile = new File(mapaDirectory, "MapaEquipas1.txt");

            } else {
                MapaFile = new File(mapaDirectory, "MapaEquipas2.txt");
            }


            Gson gson = new Gson();


            String string = "";


            try {
                BufferedReader fis2 = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(
                                new FileInputStream(MapaFile),
                                Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                int content;
                while ((content = fis2.read()) != -1) {
                    // convert to char and display it
                    string += (char) content;
                }


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Map<String, Objeto_Equipa> mapaEquipas;
            mapaEquipas = gson.fromJson(string, MapaTipoEquipas);

            Set<String> keys = mapaEquipas.keySet();
            String[] listaNomesEqs = keys.toArray(new String[keys.size()]);
            TreeMap<String, Objeto_Equipa> treeMap = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
            for (int i = 0; i < listaNomesEqs.length; i++) {
                treeMap.put(mapaEquipas.get(listaNomesEqs[i]).getFinalString(), mapaEquipas.get(listaNomesEqs[i]));
            }


            List<Objeto_Equipa> targetList = new ArrayList<>(treeMap.values());
            Classificacao = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < targetList.size(); i++) {
                Objeto_Equipa equipa = targetList.get(i);
                Classificacao.add(i, new ClassificacaoTabela("" + (i + 1), equipa.getNome(), equipa.getJogos(), equipa.getPontos(), equipa.getGolosM(), equipa.getGolosS(), equipa.getGolosM() - equipa.getGolosS()));
            }
            rv = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_three);
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            rv.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


            RVAdapterClassificacao adapter = new RVAdapterClassificacao(Classificacao, getActivity());

            rv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    };


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return null;
}

}
```

E este é o xml da activity

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/custom_tab_layout_height"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
```

Comment: Poderia postar o XML da activity? Ps. Seu root layout tem 0dp de altura

Comment: @LennoardSilva , aí está o xml da activity. Sim, tem, mas isso surge do facto de a altura estar com "match_constrain", por causa do ConstrainLayout.